# MonoDroid custom control + populate listview programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

i am pretty new to all this Monodroid stuff.

I am porting my Windows Phone Applications over to Android, so far so good as far as recreating the AXML UI but when trying to port my custom usercontrol, that inherit from the UserControl class, i can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Could someone give me a small example?

What i actually want to do is to create a custom reusable control that have a simple colored rectangle on the left and some text on its right.

I want to be able to populate a listview(don't know how to do that one either) by instanciating the control as many times as i need it.

I have no clue how to create the control itself and instanciate it to fill the listview programmatically.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend reading through [this set of tutorials](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/ListViews_and_Adapters) on Xamarin's site for an introduction to how lists work in Android. Rather than using a custom "control", it sounds like all you really want is a custom row layout, which is covered in [Part 3](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/ListViews_and_Adapters/Part_3_-_Customizing_a_ListView%27s_Appearance#Creating_a_Custom_Row_Layout).